# Overriding Default Spring Data REST Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest, querydsl

I am trying to customize a Spring Data REST + QueryDSL + JPA application to handle custom web service query parameters.  Given a simple domain model and it's repository...

```
public class Person {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    ...
}

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Person> {
}
```

I would like to be able to execute dynamic web service queries that will map to QueryDSL predicate operations in the following way:

```
/person?name=Joe  // works by default
/person?nameEndsWith=oe // resolves to path 'person.name' with operations 'ENDS_WITH'
/person?ageGreaterThan=20 // resolves to path 'person.age' with operation 'GT'
```

It would appear the easiest way to do this would be to override the default `QuerydslPredicateBuilder` that Spring Data REST uses.  This bean is created as part of the `RootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` bean creation in the `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` class.  This presents several problems.

1. There is no clear documentation as to how to override bean in the autoconfiguration classes.  I could extend `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` and override the bean method, but it is not clear if this will break any other configuration.
2. The default `HandlerMethodResolver` which utilizes the `QuerydslPredicateBuilder`, `RootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver`, is not a public class.  I would basically need to copy the code for this existing class to get it to work as intended.
3. Given the above issues, it seems odd that there is not a simpler method to customize this behavior.  Am I missing something?

What is best practice for overriding default configuration beans in Spring Data REST?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this. The solution seems to be as detailed in my question here but I am not sure how to configure it in Java 7. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384132/customizing-param-binding-for-querydsl-support

Comment: @AlanHay: Unfortunately, no.  I have gotten some functionality I wanted through a hacky solution, but I have not found a satisfactory answer to my problem.

Comment: I feel the solution outlined in my post is what you are looking for. You can use the alias functionality of the binder customizer so  that say 'nameEndsWith' can be bound as you require. Should work fine if you are on Java 8.