# Security Context in terms of QueryDslPredicateExecutor and Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring-security, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I'm building REST API on the top of Spring Data Rest. Initially all repositories where extending JpaRepository. Lately decision has been made to take a more flexible approach and use `QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T>` along with `QuerydslBinderCustomizer<Q>.`

Pretty much all `findAll` methods exposed in repositories should address two scenarios

- principal has a role `ROLE_ADMIN` then no filtering should be applied a part from `Pageable`,`Sort`
- principal does not have a role `ROLE_ADMIN` I would return only those entities which belong to the current user

Getting that done was as simple as annotating `findAll` method as below.

```
@Query("select e from Entity e where e.field = ?#{principal} or 1=?#{hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') ? 1 : 0}")
Page<Entity> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

Now I want our `findAll` to be something similar to below

```
Page<Entity> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable)
```

`Predicate` is being build from request parameters(courtesy of `@QuerydslPredicate`) and is being passed in to `RepositoryEntityController` which is all being managed by spring-data-rest which is great.

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = BASE_MAPPING, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Resources<?> getCollectionResource(@QuerydslPredicate RootResourceInformation resourceInformation,
            DefaultedPageable pageable, Sort sort, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler)
                    throws ResourceNotFoundException, HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException {
```

I want to tweak that predicate(2 scenarios as above that I want to address).
It would be something simialr to below.

```
BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder(predicateBuildFromHttpRequest);
        builder.and(predicateAddressingOurRequirements);
        builder.getValue();
```

`@PostFilter` won't be an option as return type for all repos is `Page<Entity>`.

Use case that I want to address seems to be quite common to me. Having said that I had a look at spring-data and spring-data-rest documentation and could not find anything related to my question.

Question is : Am I missing something obvious here and there is a quick win for it? or I would need to implement custom solution myself? Any comments very much appreciated!

Comment: See here for some info on customizing the bindings of the user specified parameters. Not sure if you can also add additional parameters but might be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384132/customizing-param-binding-for-querydsl-support

Comment: In addition to the above, one hacky approach would be, by means of a Servlet Filter, to actually modify the incoming request and append the additional URL parameters.

Comment: you won't be able to expose new parameter in QuerydslBinderCustomizer. It is just used for customizing default binder behaviour, ie ignorecase, custom comparison etc...

Comment: The custom filter approach is then the only way I can see then. I have used this in a similar scenario and it works but feels a bit hacky.

Answer (score 1):

The Querydsl predicates are constructed by `QuerydslAwareRootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` which is sadly package private and can't be directly extended.

However, you can make a copy of that, add your security predicate logic and then drop in your implementation instead of the former resolver.

```java
public class MyQueryDslRootResourceArgumentResolver extends RootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    // the most of the code is ommitted, the content is identical with 
    // QuerydslAwareRootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver, 
    // the important part is postProcessMethod where you can modify the predicate


    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
    protected RepositoryInvoker postProcess(MethodParameter parameter, RepositoryInvoker invoker,
                                            Class<?> domainType, Map<String, String[]> parameters) {

        Object repository = repositories.getRepositoryFor(domainType);

        if (!QueryDslPredicateExecutor.class.isInstance(repository)
                || !parameter.hasParameterAnnotation(QuerydslPredicate.class)) {
            return invoker;
        }

        ClassTypeInformation<?> type = ClassTypeInformation.from(domainType);

        QuerydslBindings bindings = factory.createBindingsFor(null, type);

        // modify your predicate here
        Predicate predicate = predicateBuilder.getPredicate(type, toMultiValueMap(parameters), bindings);

        return new QuerydslRepositoryInvokerAdapter(invoker, (QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Object>) repository, predicate);
    }


}
```

Then add you own configuration class with the custom resolver implementation.

```java
public class CustomRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public RootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver repoRequestArgumentResolver() {
        QuerydslBindingsFactory factory = applicationContext.getBean(QuerydslBindingsFactory.class);
        QuerydslPredicateBuilder predicateBuilder = new QuerydslPredicateBuilder(defaultConversionService(),
                factory.getEntityPathResolver());

        return new MyQueryDslRootResourceArgumentResolver(repositories(),
                repositoryInvokerFactory(defaultConversionService()), resourceMetadataHandlerMethodArgumentResolver(),
                predicateBuilder, factory);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach - it works! But when I added extension of  `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` to my project then 'standard' configuration process of Spring Data REST stopped working as expected, i.e. if I add SDR settings to 'application.properties' they doesn't work - all I can to do is enabling them through `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter`. For example if I want to enable  'enum translation' I need set it  [in code](https://gist.github.com/Cepr0/b1d1eabbbcd60c0266d43e5ddc073d0a) instead of just setting it in properties file like 'spring.data.rest.enable-enum-translation=true'.

Comment: Moreover, standard converters also stopped to work. I need to add them manually in the config class: [objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());](https://gist.github.com/Cepr0/b1d1eabbbcd60c0266d43e5ddc073d0a).
Have you ever encountered such a problem? Do you know how to solve it? I.e. return auto configuration of SDR back...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example project that modifies the ***Predicate*** **(that is produced by the parameters from url)** before passing it to the **repository**.

The demonstration of what David Siro explained above

https://github.com/yeldarxman/QueryDslPredicateModifier