# How can I make "or" searches using the rest api?

Tags: spring-data-rest, querydsl

I am integrating querydsl to spring data rest as explained here:
https://gist.github.com/olivergierke/decf03d4948cd58a51bc
How can I make "or" searches using the rest api? Where can I find documentation for other operators?

`?name=Fred&name=Joe&name=Jack` works with `or` but I am looking for the case where one can `or` different fields of the entity like: `?name=fred+or+email=fred`

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, it's just a case of passing multiple parameters:

```
?name=Fred&name=Joe&name=Jack //name = Fred or Joe or Jack
```

For customizing the binding to, for example, use a partial match you can use the QueryDslBinderCustomizer:

```
?name=Fr&name=J
```

See (Java 8):

https://gist.github.com/olivergierke/decf03d4948cd58a51bc

and (Java 7)

[Customizing Param Binding for QueryDSL Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384132/customizing-param-binding-for-querydsl-support)